# How to add to a data-structure in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, concatenation

I am not sure what to call the following data structure: Hash or Array.

I am trying to add a 3rd element to it. Can someone please guide me. Some explanation would be much appreciated as I am new to perl and to this forum as well.

Existing structure:

```
my $var= [
          bless( {
                   'name' => 'Name1',
                   'groupid' => '2',
                   'description' => 'Desc2'
                 }, 'my_type' ),
          bless( {
                   'name' => 'Name2',
                   'groupid' => '4',
                   'description' => 'Desc3'
                 }, 'my_type' ),
];
```

I want to add the following into it:

```
bless( {
       'name' => 'Name3',
       'groupid' => '9',
       'description' => 'Desc4'
     }, 'my_type' ),
```

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your `$var` is an "arrayref".

With array, we can `push` elements at the end:

```
my @a = (1, 2, 3);
push @a, 4;
print "@a"; # "1 2 3 4"
```

To use an arrayref as an array, we have to dereference it:

```
my $a = \@a;
push @{ $a }, 5;
print "@{$a}"; # "1 2 3 4 5"
```

In these simple cases the dereferencing can be shortened, so we could have written

```
push @$a, 5; # sic! two sigils
```

In your case this would be

```
push @$var, bless(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help. Seems hashref and arrayref are things to learn next.

Answer (score 0):

It's an arrayref. You want to push an element onto the arrayref.

```
push( @{ $var }, $obj );
```

Where object is the blessed object that you want to add.

Since it's an arrayref you need to dereference the array to push
something onto it as 'push' expects an array not a reference to one.

Comment: Since v5.14, it is ok to use the ref as argument to `push`, e.g. `push $var,$obj`

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what to call the following data structure: Hash or Array.

$var is ref to array of objects.

Add is simple:

```
my $obj = bless( { #Create object
   'name' => 'Name3',
   'groupid' => '9',
   'description' => 'Desc4'
}, 'my_type' ),
push( @$var, $obj ); #Add
```